# Show subtitle in HTML5 video player using json

Tags: json, html, youtube-api

We need to create a video player the same as the reference site below:

http://www.vagalume.com.br/selena-gomez/love-you-like-a-love-song.html

What we need to achieve is to create a `HTML5` player which plays youtube video with subtitle dynamically.

I have added one link above which is our reference link and we need to make the same functionality given in reference site.

Here is our HTML page code:

```
<code>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('audio, video').mediaelementplayer({
        alwaysShowControls: true,
        videoVolume: 'horizontal',
        features: ['playpause','progress','volume','fullscreen'],
        startLanguage: 'en'
    });
});
</code>
```

Our video player code:

```
<code>
video id="video" preload="metadata" controls="controls">
            source type="video/youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FV4cwmM79NY">
        /video>
</code>
```

Here is our JavaScript code for adding subtitles dynamically.

```
<code>
(function() {
    var video = document.getElementById("video"), i, track,     loadcues = document.getElementById("loadcues"), hideTracks = function() {
            for (i = 0; i < video.textTracks.length; i++) {
                video.textTracks[i].mode = "hidden";
            }
        };
    trackdisplay();
    function trackdisplay(){
    hideTracks();
        track = video.addTextTrack("captions", "English", "en");
        track.mode = "showing";
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(0, 12, "Loaded Cues"));
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(18.7, 21.5, "This blade has a dark past."));
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(22.8, 26.8, "It has shed much innocent blood."));
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(29, 32.45, "You're a fool for traveling alone, so completely unprepared."));
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(32.75, 35.8, "You're lucky your blood's still flowing."));
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(36.25, 37.3, "Thank you."));
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(38.5, 40, "So..."));
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(40.4, 44.8, "What brings you to the land of the gatekeepers?"));
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(46, 48.5, "I'm searching for someone."));
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(49, 53.2, "Someone very dear? A kindred spirit?"));
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(54.4, 56, "A dragon."));
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(58.85, 61.75, "A dangerous quest for a lone hunter."));
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(62.95, 65.87, "I've been alone for as long as I can remember."));
        track.addCue(new VTTCue(118.25, 119.5, "We're almost done. Shhh..."));
}
    //loadcues.addEventListener("click", function() {

    //});
}());
</code>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. You are new to this site, so this can probably help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hello, Thanks for you prompt reply, I have update my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way i found on Html5Rocks and it includes making the subtitles you showed us in a .vtt file and including it in your video tag as 
  `<track kind="subtitles" label="English subtitles" src="subtitles_en.vtt" srclang="en" default></track>`. Where label is the language of the subtitles, src is where the .vtt file is. You can get all the new VTT cue and remove them from your js and add them in a file of your desire. So your video should look something like this

```
     <code>
    video id="video" preload="metadata" controls="controls">
                source type="video/youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FV4cwmM79NY">
<track kind="subtitles" label="English subtitles" src="*VTT file's place*" srclang="en" default></track>


 /video>
    </code>
```

EDIT: For the JSON you can do this

```
multiCell
00:01:15.200 --> 00:02:18.800
{
"title": "Multi-celled organisms",
"description": "Multi-celled organisms have different types of cells that perform specialised functions.
  Most life that can be seen with the naked eye is multi-cellular. These organisms are though to
  have evolved around 1 billion years ago with plants, animals and fungi having independent
  evolutionary paths.",
"src": "multiCell.jpg",
"href": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicellular"
}

insects
00:02:18.800 --> 00:03:01.600
{
"title": "Insects",
"description": "Insects are the most diverse group of animals on the planet with estimates for the total
  number of current species range from two million to 50 million. The first insects appeared around
  400 million years ago, identifiable by a hard exoskeleton, three-part body, six legs, compound eyes
  and antennae.",
"src": "insects.jpg",
"href": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insects"
}
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your reply,

We actually want the subtitle display with the help of json not VTT, SRT etc files.

Could you please help us to show subtitle using json.

Thanks

Comment: You can use JSON just call the file VTT. Just see this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/#toc-jsoncues

Comment: Not that have i tested it or something. I think it would work even if the file is .json

Comment: Hi,

I have did the same but it is working with the html5 video not with the youtube video.

I just want to play Youtube video in HTML5 custom player and display subtitle below the video player.

Please let us know if you did something like I explain above.

Thanks
KK